# Redshift COPY throws error but 'stl_load_errors' system table does not provide details

Tags: amazon-redshift

When I attempt to copy a CSV from S3 into a new table in Redshift (which normally works for other tables) I get this error

> ERROR:  Load into table 'table_name' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors'
> system table for details.

But, when I run the standard query to investigate stl_load_errors

```
SELECT errors.tbl, info.table_id::integer, info.table_id, *
FROM stl_load_errors errors
INNER JOIN svv_table_info info
  ON errors.tbl = info.table_id
```

I don't see any results related to this COPY. I see errors from previous failed COPY commands, but none related to the most recent one that I am interested in.

Comment: Please make sure that you are querying stl_load_errors table with same user you are performing COPY command. You can also try to avoid using ssv_table_info table in query or change INNER to LEFT join.

Comment: This was it. Feel free to post as a full answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure that you are querying **stl_load_errors** table with same user you are performing COPY command. You can also try to avoid using **ssv_table_info** table in query or change INNER to LEFT join.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM stl_load_errors errors` was all I needed